# How I replace every words to like this?

Tags: javascript

```
var x = "Hello+world + like+ this + name,bla";
x = x.replace(/* RegEx */, function(x){
    return "*" + x + "*";
});
alert(x); // Output will be " *Hello*+*World*+*like*+*name*+*bla* ";
```

How I do this with js and regEx

Comment: what's the logic for regex ?

Comment: Why not just split?

Comment: Agolo : I don't no about regEx....But i feel it is and...

Comment: Is `this` really to be removed from the string, and are commas supposed to be removed?

Comment: Why there is no comma or space in your output? And `this`?

Comment: Because I want no to replaced + and ,

Comment: Only replace these words

Comment: have you tried researching this on your own?  there are tons of tutorials for regular expressions on the internet.  RegexHero.net even has a live testing tool.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`/[a-z]+/gi` will look for any sequence of letters that are at least one chracter long. If the word could contain numbers and `_` as in variable names then use `/\w+/g`.

```js
var x = "Hello+world + like+ this + name,bla";
x = x.replace(/[a-z]+/gi, function(x){
    return "*" + x + "*";
});
alert(x);
```

Comment: This doesn't look like it would handle the comma delimiter.

Comment: @ScottMarcus Yeah I just saw his desired output! The `this` is missing too!